# Form Runner Xerces version error

Tags: orbeon

I just installed Orbeon 4.4 under Tomcat 7.0.42.

From `http://<mylocalhost>:8080/orbeon/home` I click on the Form Runner Home link.

I get an error box: There was an error running the process. Please contact the application administrator.

In the Tomcat's log there is this error:

```
--------------------------------------------
Looking for a valid Parser...

Checking for Xerces, found version Xerces-J 2.11.0 needed version Xerces-J 2.9.0
Warning: Failed find a valid Parser!

Please add an appropriate Parser to the class-path, e.g. in the 'endorsed' folder of the servlet container or in the 'endorsed' folder of the JRE.

Using parser org.orbeon.oxf.xml.xerces.XercesSAXParser
Using transformer com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
--------------------------------------------
```

I tried to put the 2.9.0 instead the native 2.11.0 in the orbeon/WEB-INF/lib folder but the application doesn't start.

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning, not an error. Orbeon Forms should run just fine with the newer parser.